# doctype location - wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

So I have a site created via  wordpress. My problem is that the doctype is declared after a div which is  I think is wrong. but since I'm using wordpress I put the doctype tag on my header but my header is inside a div.

[header content](http://prntscr.com/53if2y)

```
<div class="row" >
    <?php get_header(); ?> // <-- doctype loads here
        <div id="content">
            <div class="twelve columns clearfix">
                <section class="nine columns clearfix" itemprop="articleBody" style="border-right: 1px solid #a79c7f;  min-height:450px !important;">
                    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                    <?php query_posts('category_name=post da');  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"target="_blank" ><h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?></a>
                    <hr>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </section> 
                    <?php if (function_exists('page_navi')) { // if expirimental feature is active ?>
                        <?php page_navi(); // use the page navi function ?>
                    <?php } else { // if it is disabled, display regular wp prev & next links ?>
                        <nav class="wp-prev-next">
                            <ul class="clearfix">
                                <li class="prev-link"><?php next_posts_link(_e('&laquo; Older Entries', "bonestheme")) ?></li>
                                <li class="next-link"><?php previous_posts_link(_e('Newer Entries &raquo;', "bonestheme")) ?></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    <?php } ?>      
                    <?php else : ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
            </div> <!-- end #main -->
        </div> <!-- end #content -->
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
</div> <!-- end .row-->
```

Now I know this can be resolve by removing the doctype tag inside the header and placing it before

`<div class="row" >`

but it will be redundant to put it on every template that I create. is there anything I can do to other than putting my doctype to every page like the way I'm using with the header but in a correct order.

I can't exchange the place of the header to my row because the design will break.

---

ANOTHER QUESTION: Is it possible to start a div from my header and not placing the closing tag to the header but placing it on the footer. will that work? so i can place the starting div row after the doctype tag on the header instead of placing it before the whole header.

Comment: First of all, what is use of `<div class="row" >` ?Why is it too much important ?

Comment: the row has a style of box-shadow which holds the entire site.

Comment: Can you provide your full `header.php` file ?

Comment: I already fixed the problem. posted the answer.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I already fixed the problem by putting the div row inside the header.php file after the  doctype tag.
then removing all the row i declare on every template. the closing tag is locatedat the footer before the html and body is closed. everything is fixed i think for now. :)

```
<!doctype html>  
<!--[if IEMobile 7 ]> <html <?php language_attributes(); ?>class="no-js iem7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|(gt IEMobile 7)|!(IEMobile)|!(IE)]><!--><html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="Hotel Frederiksminde" content="Wordpress Site of Hotel Frederiksminde." />
        <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?><?php wp_title( '&laquo;', true, 'left'); ?> </title>
        <meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>" />             
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- icons & favicons -->
        <!-- For iPhone 4 -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/icons/h/apple-touch-icon.png">
        <!-- For iPad 1-->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/icons/m/apple-touch-icon.png">
        <!-- For iPhone 3G, iPod Touch and Android -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/icons/l/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">
        <!-- For Nokia -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/icons/l/apple-touch-icon.png">
        <!-- For everything else -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/hotelfs.png" /> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css" type="text/css" />
        <!-- media-queries.js (fallback) -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>           
        <![endif]-->
        <!-- html5.js -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>">
        <!-- wordpress head functions -->
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
        <!-- end of wordpress head -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
        <!-- bring in theme options styles -->
        <?php 
        $heading_typography = of_get_option('heading_typography');
        if ($heading_typography) {
            $theme_options_styles = '
            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{ 
                font-family: ' . $heading_typography['face'] . '; 
                font-weight: ' . $heading_typography['style'] . '; 
                color: ' . $heading_typography['color'] . '; 
            }';
        }
        $main_body_typography = of_get_option('main_body_typography');
        if ($main_body_typography) {
            $theme_options_styles .= '
            body{ 
                font-family: ' . $main_body_typography['face'] . '; 
                font-weight: ' . $main_body_typography['style'] . '; 
                color: ' . $main_body_typography['color'] . '; 
            }';
        }
        $link_color = of_get_option('link_color');
        if ($link_color) {
            $theme_options_styles .= '
            a{ 
                color: ' . $link_color . '; 
            }';
        }
        $link_hover_color = of_get_option('link_hover_color');
        if ($link_hover_color) {
            $theme_options_styles .= '
            a:hover{ 
                color: ' . $link_hover_color . '; 
            }';
        }
        $link_active_color = of_get_option('link_active_color');
        if ($link_active_color) {
            $theme_options_styles .= '
            a:active{ 
                color: ' . $link_active_color . '; 
            }';
        }
        $topbar_bg_color = of_get_option('top_nav_bg_color');
        if ($topbar_bg_color) {
            $theme_options_styles .= '
            .top-nav { 
                background-color: '. $topbar_bg_color . ';
            }';
        }
        $topbar_link_color = of_get_option('top_nav_link_color');
        if ($topbar_link_color) {
            $theme_options_styles .= '
            .top-nav > li > a { 
                color: '. $topbar_link_color . ' !important;
            }';
        }
        $topbar_link_hover_color = of_get_option('top_nav_link_hover_color');
        if ($topbar_link_hover_color) {
            $theme_options_styles .= '
            .top-nav > li > a:hover { 
                color: '. $topbar_link_hover_color . ' !important;
            }';
        }
        $suppress_comments_message = of_get_option('suppress_comments_message');
        if ($suppress_comments_message){
            $theme_options_styles .= '
            #main article {
                border-bottom: none;
            }';
        }       
        if($theme_options_styles){
            echo '<style>' 
            . $theme_options_styles . '
            </style>';
        }
        ?>  
    <style>
    #glt-translate-trigger {
        background: #9f6330;
        color: #ffffff;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .goog-te-combo {
        height: 20px !important;
        top: -5px;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 11px;
    }
    #google_language_translator {
        height: 20px;
        width: 100px;
        float: right;
    }
    .goog-te-gadget .goog-te-combo {
        margin: 4px 0;
        width: 100px !important;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 874px) {
    .goog-te-gadget .goog-te-combo {
        display:none;
    }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 844px) {
    #glt-translate-trigger {
        height: 10px;
        font-size: 10px ;
        }
    }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<div class="row" > // DIV STARTS HERE
            <header role="banner" id="top-header">
        <div class="twelve columns" style="background: transparent; padding:0px !important;" >  
            <section class="twelve columns text-center" style="background: transparent;">
                <a href="http://fabioide.com/frederiksminde/velkommen"><img src="http://fabioide.com/frederiksminde/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/fredlogo.png" alt="Hotel Frederiksminde Logo" style="height:100px; width:410px;"></a>
            </section>

            <section class="twelve columns text-center" style="background: transparent;padding:0px !important;  ">
                <div class="menuimg">
                <img src="http://fabioide.com/frederiksminde/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/menu.jpg" style="width:30px; height:30px;" alt="Mobile Menu" >
                </div>

<div id="navcontainer"> 
                <?php // Navigation that display all pages. ?>
                <?php // wp_nav_menu( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container' => false, 'theme_location' => 'The Main Menu Dansk', 'exclude' => '479' ) ); ?>

                    <?php  if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar2' ) ) : ?>
                <?php  dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar2' ); ?>
                    <?php  else : ?>
                <!-- This content shows up if there are no widgets defined in the backend. -->
                    <div class="alert-box">Please activate some Widgets.</div>
            <?php  endif; ?>

            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="twelve columns" style="background: transparent; padding:0px;" >  
            <div class="slider">
            <?php masterslider(1); ?>
            </div>
                </header> <!-- end header -->
```

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner here's the answer.

Comment: This is not valid HTML.

Comment: then what should i put? and why is it invalid?

Comment: You should not have any divs (or other like elements) outside of the <body> tag.

Comment: so I need to place the div row after the body then its valid? everything is working fine right now. what would be the future problem or possible problem that can occur right now?

Comment: With a `<div>` outside of `<body>` you're relying on each and every browser to notice that you've made a mistake. Hopefully, they DO notice, and ignore it. However, most likely, some browsers won't.

Comment: already place the div row after the body tag. thanks for the notice.